# Chrome extension to monitor a kiosk and reload if needed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, kiosk

I have a kiosk that processes portraits of people. It is running in chrome.

One out of 200 people who use the kiosk end up with it freezing during the process. When it freezes, I never get the "ah snap" and the page just kinda hangs.

I was wondering if it is possible to make an extension to monitor the page and check for a heartbeat - If it is not seen after 30 seconds reload the window.

Any help would be great.

Comment: This should not happen. You should debug your application running in your chrome browser! Sounds like you run out of memory - do you remove old portraits?

Comment: I agree. But it's not that simple. it's not memory related. Some of the kiosks will process thousands of people before it happens, but it could happen twice in a row. It could be a canvas error as when it crashes the face image in the canvas turns to a red and black circle. And im never doing a fill where anything like that should happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Have a content script in the kiosk page send a message every X seconds back to the background page

   In the content script:

   ```
   var port = chrome.extension.connect({ name: "keep-alive" });

   port.postMessage('is-alive', { alive: true });

   setInterval(function () {
       port.postMessage('is-alive', { alive: true });
   }, 1000 * 15);
   ```
2. If the background page detects the message hasn't come back after a certain time then reload the tab

   In the background page:

   ```
   var last = Date.now();
   var interval = 1000 * 15;

   chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
       if (port.name === 'keep-alive') {
           port.onMessage.addListener(function (data) {
               if (data.type === 'is-alive' && data.payload.alive === true) {
                   last = Date.now();
               }
           });
       }
   });

   setInterval(function () {
       if (Date.now() - last > interval) {
           // Reload the tab...
       }
   }, interval);
   ```

For information about reloading the tab, see the [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) documentation. You will need to add `tabs` to your permission list in the manifest.

If you'd like to know more about message passing, see the [Messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) docs.

Comment: "Reload the tab" -> Have a look at the [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) API.